# Starting next video in an array after 10 seconds of ended current video in JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm currently building an html 5 video player and got a bit stuck. What I am looking for is after a video is done playing a prompt fades in right after the video is over displaying the title of the next video for the user to click to go right to the next video.

If the user doesn't interact after 10 seconds the video player will automatically play the next video. I have the js calls for end of the video to start the timer, the thing I cant seem to wrap my head around is grabbing the next video in the list.

You can see what i have going on here so far:
http://xeroproject.com/hopkins/

Any help would be great. Thanks

The code.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#videoarea").bind("ended", function() {
      /*alert('Video ended!');*/
      theTimer();
    });


    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
      $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": "",
        "autoplay": "autoplay"
      })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
      "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
      "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
  })
});

function theTimer() {
  var timeleft = 10;
  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
    if (timeleft <= 0)
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    nextVideo();
  }, 1000);
}

function nextVideo() {
  $("#videoarea").attr({
    "src": $("#playlist li").eq(+1).attr("movieurl"),

  });
}
```

```css
#playlist {
  display: table;
}

#playlist li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
}

#playlist li:hover {
  color: blue;
}

#videoarea {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 1920px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="videoarea" controls poster="" src=""></video>

<div class="c12">
  <p> Next video will begin in <span id="countdowntimer">10 </span> Seconds</p>
</div>

<ul id="playlist">
  <li movieurl="https://player.vimeo.com/external/134503961.hd.mp4?s=cb119bb3aba91ce422389eaa8deb56474b2a33ae&profile_id=113">REEL</li>
  <li movieurl="https://player.vimeo.com/external/152628566.hd.mp4?s=91d67ce6b5c2a0ba58f2b4e383d9f5111d62012d&profile_id=119">COMBAT PHOTOGS</li>
  <li movieurl="https://player.vimeo.com/external/174551908.hd.mp4?s=09b9278046d28659c205f4a201eef33ba491d570&profile_id=119">RUNA</li>
</ul>
```

:

Comment: Where in the source code do you attempt to set the new/next video to play? I can't seem to find any attempt of you doing that...

Comment: Ive adjusted the code a bit since I posted. I have it making a call in the js to the next video. Two new problems: 1 its not auto playing and 2. Its loading it on every second instead of at the end of the 10 seconds:


Sorry im new to adding a lot of code and having a hard time getting it all in there.

http://xeroproject.com/hopkins/

and the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqn6qvsp/

Comment: Please show your attempt(s) of making the next video play and I'm some someone or myself will be able to explain why it isn't functioning as intended. My guess would be you are trying to set the new video within the interval rather than within the if condition where the `clearInterval()` is, that would also be where you will want to listen for the new video file to be loaded to trigger the play function but without seeing your attempt it's impossible to say why your attempt isn't working.

Comment: this is the js call to the new video:

<script>
 function nextVideo(){
  $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(+1).attr("movieurl"),
  
    })

      }
 
 </script>

Comment: and this is the timer:

<script type="text/javascript">
    function theTimer(){
    var timeleft = 10;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
    if(timeleft <= 0)
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
  nextVideo();
  
    },1000);
 }
</script>

Its sort of working in a sense its loading the next one but its loading it ever one second and not at the end.

Comment: Ah yes, I see you have edited your comment and provided a jsfiddle with your attempt. I will update your question and add that into your snippet to make it easier for others to find when reading your question.

Comment: Thanks i keep closing my comment trying to add code in it...sorry

Comment: Not a problem. I have updated your snippet and I will now take a look and see if I can identify the problem and come up with a solution.

Comment: I have found the problem with the video loading over multiple times. You didn't wrap your `if` condition so it didn't have a start or end if that condition returned true. https://jsfiddle.net/56b3gg3x/ and a quick edit to play the next video https://jsfiddle.net/v1jcf7bh/

Comment: I would recommend you clean up some of the source code though because some of it makes no sense. `$(window).on('load', function(){ $(function() {` This is 2 DOM ready functions, one inside of another....

Comment: Thanks! that seems to have solved the issue with the laod. I also am going to need to define and ID up front I think because my nextVideo() seems to just be adding a 1 as the ID and not adding 1 + the current ID.

Yeah i will need a lot of clean up I'm sure since I'm sort of learning this piece by piece.

Comment: I got a lot of this figured out:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lqn6qvsp/1/

The one small last thing I cant seem to get is on button click i need to kill the timer. Which seems lame since it should be so easy...Other than that you help went a long way I appreciate it.